# pod install Unable to add source

Tags: ios, git, restkit, cocoapods

I want to do pod install, but i got these error.

**Error**:

```
Analyzing dependencies
Cloning spec repo `wackadoo` from `gitATgithub.com:Repo/Repo.git`
[!] Unable to add a source with url `gitATgithub.com:Repo/Repo.git` named `Repo`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I think it could be my git config.
When i do a git clone, i musst enter my username and Password.
Is that right?

**My Podfile**

```
source 'git@github.com:sample/sample.git'
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

pod 'RestKit', '~>  0.20.0'
pod 'TestLibrary', :git => 'https://github.com/sample/sample2'
pod 'libARClientIOS', :path => '~/Developer/Test/iPhone/libARClientIOS/'

post_install do |installer|
  installer.project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |configuration|
      target.build_settings(configuration.name)['ARCHS'] = '$(ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT)'
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I change the source address from git@ to https:// 
I think i haven't configured my ssh key to git.

Answer (score 16):

You forgot to set your newly install Xcode path on command-line tool. **Xcode-->Preferences-->Locations-->Command line tool --> set your Xcode.**

Comment: Thanks buddy. small thing but very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Solution that works for me is to update cocoa pods gem by:

```
sudo gem uninstall cocoapods
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

and to remove that line 
    source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
from Podfile. and let it get the repo from its own configuration.

Comment: I tried every other solution, however this helped me. Thanks buddy

Answer (score 0):

This was working fine earlier. However, when I switched to Xcode 8.1 this issue poped-up.
Reason for issue is that **Command Line Tools required for install pod is not selected in Xcode settings.**

This can be done using below steps :

1. Press **cmd+comma** (,) to open Xcode **Preferences** (shortcut key)
2. Goto **Locations** tab (last one)
3. From **Command Line Tools** option **select the Xcode** you are using to build your app.
4. Now pod install command should work.

[image: Screenshot added]